# Some issues while running react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I'm facing these issues the whole day - fixing one to face another one ‍♂️

what's the issue here? - after executing this command

> react-native run-android?

the full error :

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   /Users/mohsen/Desktop/roam - copy/roam/roam/android/app/src/main/java/host/exp/exponent/MainApplication.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
>
> return BuildVariantConstants.USE_INTERNET_KERNEL;
>              ^
>     symbol:   variable BuildVariantConstants
>     location: class MainApplication
>   1 error
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem in your MainApplication.java. Look for any syntax problem or any other issue you get there. After that you can open Android studio sync your project and see if you get any error there. Update build tools from there if necessary. Maybe it will be sorted by then.